# Is there a way to accept only unknown options and not unknown arguments?

Tags: python-click

With subcommands, the root command cannot accept unknown arguments because the application would think they're subcommands, but it should theoretically still be able to accept an unknown number of options; however, using something like `@click.argument("args", nargs=-1)` on the root command would accept both arguments *and* options, rendering the subcommands unusable.

Is there any way to accept only the unknown options, and treat the arguments as subcommands?